# screenshot image from vtkRenderWindow without borders

Tags: java, image, vtk

I tried everything I found to save just my image without borders without success.
My image is 124x126, so when the image is saved it's always with borders and new size 300x300, If I use another program to select only my image it's 208x209.
so I don't know why my image is scaled and why it's always 300x300, If I change the size of vtkRenderWindow to 124x126 the borders are still there and my image is shrunk. 
My question is how I can save my image of 124x126 without borders?

```
        mapper.SetInputConnection(polyDataReader.GetOutputPort()); 
        vtkActor actor = new vtkActor(); 
        actor.SetMapper(mapper); 
        actor.GetBounds(bounds); 
        System.out.println("actor: " + bounds[1] + " x " + bounds[3]);    // 124x126 (everything's ok)

        //Create a renderer, render window, and interactor 
        vtkRenderer renderer = new vtkRenderer(); 

        vtkRenderWindow renderWindow = new vtkRenderWindow(); 
        renderWindow.BordersOff();      // the borders are still there     
        renderWindow.AddRenderer(renderer); 

        vtkRenderWindowInteractor renderWindowInteractor = new vtkRenderWindowInteractor(); 
        renderWindowInteractor.SetRenderWindow(renderWindow); 


        //Add the actor to the scene 
        renderer.AddActor(actor); 
        renderer.SetBackground(0, 0, 0); 


        //Render and interact 
        renderWindow.Render(); 

        //screenshot code: 
        vtkWindowToImageFilter w2if = new vtkWindowToImageFilter(); 
        w2if.SetInput(renderWindow); 
        w2if.Update(); 

        vtkPNGWriter writer = new vtkPNGWriter(); 
        writer.SetFileName("out.png");      //my image with borders 300x300 !!!!??
        writer.SetInputData(w2if.GetOutput()); 
        writer.Write();
```

[image: image saved with borders]

ps: sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

It is because your renderwindow has the default size of 300x300.

What you have to realize is that the polydata is rendered in a 3D scene, and what you call "borders" is the background, the amount of which depends on the zoom level, i.e. on your camera's position. To get what you want, you need to do two things:

- Resize renderwindow to desired image size:

`renderWindow.SetSize(bounds[1], bounds[3]);`

- Reposition camera so that the actor fills the viewport completely. Try

`renderer.GetActiveCamera().SetParallelScale(1); // we want parallel projection
renderer.GetActiveCamera().SetParallelScale(0.5 * (bounds[3] - bounds[2])); // zoom`

The bounds in zoom may be 0.5 * (bounds[1] - bounds[0]), not exactly sure which side of the rectangle it should be.

Hope this helps,

Miro

Comment: Thanks I don't know why your code doesn't work for me, but I tried this one and it works, but I don't know how to calculate the value **245** from my values hier I put it because it's the one that gives me the right zoom.
`camera.SetPosition((bounds[1]-bounds[0])*0.5, (bounds[3]-bounds[2])*0.5, 245.0); camera.SetFocalPoint((bounds[1]-bounds[0])*0.5, (bounds[3]-bounds[2])*0.5, 0.0);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean "it doesn't work for me"? 

You most certainly want to place the camera in the middle of the bounds, so it should be (bounds[0] + bounds[1])*0.5 in your code, plus not minus.
The 245 is the camera distance and it is a factor of the view angle and the size of the object. If you draw it on the paper, with a little trigonometry you can figure it out. But if you don't have parallel projection set, your image may suffer from projection deformation, much like railroad tracks are converging on a painting even though they are parallel in real life.